# report viewer control barcode field squeezed when printed

Tags: asp.net, printing, ssrs-2008-r2, iis-8.5, rdl

So I have a report (RDL) that has a bar code field on it. I have a report viewer control on an aspx page that will display the report correctly in preview mode on the page, including the bar code.

Bar Code Image from Report Preview:

[image]

When the report is printed from within VS2015/2017 it will print fine. When I print from SSRS it will print fine.

When I publish the web app to IIS server and try to print the report the bar code is squeezed horizontally...

Bar Code Image from IIS Server when printed:

[image]

This causes the bar code to be unusable. Is there something I am missing to make the bar code NOT be squeezed when printed from the IIS server. I have tried to Google and search for anything to do with printing from IIS involving SSRS and ASP.NET but I cannot seem to find anything that has to do directly with this situation.

I have the bar code font installed on the following:

SSRS server (Which is 2008R2)

IIS server (Which IIS8.5)

Client systems (Windows 7 & 10)

How do I keep the bar code from being squeezed down?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No one has any ideas on this??

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I had to eventually reboot the server. Just restarting the SSRS service was not enough to clear this problem.